# DR - Missing binlogs in Maxwell

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, disaster-recovery, change-data-capture

We have a standard `db.r6g.2xlarge` RDS MySQL instance running in production with 2 replicas. Maxwell CDC is setup to publish binlogs to a Kafka topic.

From a RPO point of view: in the worst case (say RDS stuck in "failed" state) we might have to go for PITR which could result in upto 5 mins of data loss. We are currently thinking about leveraging the CDC topic to reconstruct the queries and replay them to recover the last 5 mins of data (whatever is possible).

Given above, is there a possibility (however remote) where binlogs were written but are not available in the CDC topic? I am thinking situations like disk crashes, corruption, etc.